Laravel route model binding in laravel 11 doesn’t work for routes in a customized route file
In my laravel 11 app I created a route file named admin.php to put my admin routes there.
I configured admin.php in bootstrap app.php based on laravel’s documentation this way:
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        apiPrefix: '',
        then: function () {
            Route::prefix('')
                ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
        },
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        $exceptions->shouldRenderJsonWhen(fn() => true);
    })
    ->create();

It worked fine until I wanted to use Route Model Binding.
It returns [] as the result of any model it finds although the record exists in the database. 
Consider this route:
Route::get('fundraisers/{fundraiser}', function (Fundraiser $fundraiser) {
    dd($fundraiser);
});

This is the result of putting the route in api.php:
#attributes: array:12 [
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "name"
    "national_id" => "111111111"
    "registration_number" => "1111111111"
    "registration_date" => "2011-11-11"
    "address" => "address"
    "postal_code" => "1111111"
    "legal_type" => null
    "info" => null
    "phone" => "09121111121"
    "created_at" => "2024-07-01 17:36:21"
    "updated_at" => "2024-07-01 17:36:21"
  ]

This is the result of putting the route in admin.php:
[]

The problem seemed to be about then: so I used web: in app.php.
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        apiPrefix: '',
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/admin.php',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        $exceptions->shouldRenderJsonWhen(fn() => true);
    })
    ->create();

It applied csrf token. So I used ->withoutMiddleware('web') it didn't help me with route model binding.
If I use any other fields like console, channel and etc, the route model binding issue persists.
I need your help!

is it throws any specific error regarding model bonding?

Also check if it php artisan route:list returns the expected routes that you defined in the admin.php

no, just returns an empty array

the routes work fine and i can get list of them. they don't work when i use route model binding.

Okay. are you sure you have imported this use App\Models\Fundraiser model  to the top of the admin.php route file?

yes. the problem was about the middleware group. i had to create a middleware group including SubstituteBindings and add it to middlewares of admin.php

You need to add the SubstituteBindings middleware
its a default middleware in web and api
as you removed 'web' middleware so its removed from the request cycle
if you want to get aware of csrf just change 'web' to 'api'
check this documentation :
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/middleware#laravels-default-middleware-groups

this one saved me. i added 'admin-api' middleware group to app.php withMiddleware and i passed SubstituteBindings to it and then used 'admin-api' middleware as middleware for admin.php.
